# Dynamically change group and child text size which in ExpandableListView at DrawerLayout from preference

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

How can i dynamically  change group and child text size which in ExpandableListView at DrawerLayout from preference ?

```
public class HadithExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {

        public HadithExpandableListAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context,
                int groupLayout, int childLayout, String[] groupFrom,
                int[] groupTo, String[] childrenFrom, int[] childrenTo) {
            super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo,
                    childLayout, childrenFrom, childrenTo);
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
            int groupPos = groupCursor.getPosition();

            Cursor childCursor = mDbHelper
                    .selectQuery("SELECT [HadithID] as _id,[HadithTitel] ,ChapterID FROM [Hadith] where ChapterID="
                            + groupPos);
            getActivity().startManagingCursor(childCursor);
            childCursor.moveToFirst();
            getActivity().stopManagingCursor(childCursor);
            return childCursor;
        }
}
```